# How to tell which of these APIs are open/test/public?

Tags: api

If I had more web dev/API experience I think I'd know how to comb through the below list of 112 APIs to identify which if any are the open/test/public APIs, but since I've been unable to do this so far, I'm wondering whether any of you might be able to help me find them, if there are any, in the list.

https://www.programmableweb.com/category/insurance/api

Cheers,
R.

Comment: All should be public, most will be behind a paywall, open the link for Solaria as a sample https://www.programmableweb.com/api/solaria-labs-shine-rest-api-v10 you will see API Key meaning you need an account.

Comment: Ok do you know which of these APIs wouldn't require hosting a 3rd party iframe? I would like to know which I can use to populate life insurance quotes from large insurance companies, while collecting as much user info as possible, hence no iframe.

Comment: There is no defined search for it, you would need to write a scrubber to data-mine the site as I am not sure that they have an API (ironic) perhaps you contact them

Comment: none need an IFrame, they are API's you can access then via javascript and say jquery but that would expose your key to the world and is a bad idea in my opinion. Better would be to make your own API to call their API and protect your service with a firewall like found at www.asp-waf.com and limit access via configuration to access from your own domain using the annotation https://firewallapi.asp-waf.com/?topic=/html/T-Walter.Web.FireWall.Annotations.ModelFilterAttribute.htm

Comment: Ok, I suppose I can think about building my own secure API in the way you described, and I suppose I could build such an API from scratch, but do you know whether some open source/test APIs like this already exist? and if so where I would be able to find them? I found none that fit your description at https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis, but do you know of other similar open source API repos? At some point, if I still can't find one that fits, I'll seriously consider building one from scratch. Also, thanks very much for your feedback thus far, it's been great.

Comment: what API are you looking for, stocks, news, facebook... did you use the search option?

Comment: All good, I'll take it from here, thanks again!